# update mysqlnd_ms configuration without restarting

Tags: php, mysqlnd

Is there a way to update the mysqlnd_ms configuration on a Linux server (PHP-FPM) without forcing a restart?

For example, if I add or remove a slave database, I'd like that to be updated in the PHP-FPM server without forcing a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading (instead of restarting) re-reads configuration files, including the MySQLND_MS settings.

Example: service php-fpm reload